# C++ thread side effects

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm performing many operations on a array and would like to multi-thread it using pthreads. How can I have multiple threads access and edit the same array concurrently? I will algorithmically prevent memory assess collisions, so that is not a concern.

I am manipulating a class, which is essentially a wrapper to turn an array of object into a 2D matrix, with several useful methods to simplify this task. Each cell is being manipulated separably to every other, so I was planning to pass the same object to 4 identical threads, but give each thread a different part to work on.

I've never used threading properly before, and this mess of (seemingly unnecessary) voids and pointers is confusing me a little.

thanks

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to have multiple threads access the same memory. Usually, people do something special to have that *not* happen.

Comment: Why pthreads as opposed to `std::thread` or `std::async`?

Comment: After doing a quick Google for c++ threading, almost all of the results that came up were for pThreads, I assumed they were the most commonly used system. Really I'd like to use whatever system ports to the three main OSs best.